# OpenLayers 3.5 WFS-T update to GeoServer 2.7 raises StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers, html, wfs-t

I am using ol.format.WFS.writeTransaction() (OL3.5) to generate WFS-T statements. This works well for insert and delete. The problem is with the update statement.

Any update statement returns following exception from GeoServer:

```
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
<ows:ExceptionText>java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 String index out of range: -1</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
```

Edits via QGIS work as expected.

This is an example POST generated by OL3.5

```
<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Update typeName="feature:playa_poly_noattribute" xmlns:feature="http://argeomatica.com">
    <Property>
      <Name>boundedBy</Name>
      <Value>-9693316.43121855,2347365.748407976,-9692555.877885746,2347961.5151853375</Value>
    </Property>
    <Property>
      <Name>geometry</Name>
      <Value>
        <Polygon xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
          <exterior>
            <LinearRing>
              <posList>-9693072.420357607 2347961.5151853375 -9693316.43121855 2347628.7731022364 -9692822.071552228 2347365.748407976 -9692555.877885746 2347758.700963257 -9692555.877885746 2347758.700963257 -9692737.951605482 2347825.076779921 -9692893.214319186 2347748.042587353 -9693072.420357607 2347961.5151853375</posList>
            </LinearRing>
          </exterior>
        </Polygon>
      </Value>
   </Property>
   <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
     <FeatureId fid="playa_poly_noattribute.1"></FeatureId>
   </Filter>
 </Update>
</Transaction>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because boundedBy / bbox is a property that OpenLayers creates when parsing the GML, it is not a real feature property. So when you update, you should clone the feature and get rid of it. Some example code:

```
// do a WFS transaction to update the geometry
var properties = feature.getProperties();
// get rid of bbox which is not a real property
delete properties.bbox;
var clone = new ol.Feature(properties);
clone.setId(fid);
```

If you need more example code, here is the code we use in the OpenGeo Suite SDK for WFS-T: https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/blob/master/sdk/src/main/resources/client/ol3-common/app/TransactionHandler.js#L105:L110

Comment: Thanks Bart. That makes complete sense to me. I will only get to test this on Monday but I am sure that this will work. I will also have a read through the SDK code for future reference. I already used your excellent [guide](http://boundlessgeo.com/2014/06/openlayers-editing-wfs-t/) on the Boundless website to get started with WFS-T editing. Maybe you can add a quick note in regard to this issue in the section on updates.

Comment: Hi Bart, I just got around to test this. Works like a treat. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Although @bartvde's solution works, it's a bit cumbersome to clone the Feature and create bring over ID and properties. Also, there's a risk that something else is missing in the cloned feature.

I'd like to propose another solution:

```js
feature.unset("boundedBy"); // or "bbox", depending on name of the feature you want to get rid of
```

That's all it takes!

---

Below, you can see a more complete solution that creates an object `features` that contains `inserts`, `updates` and `deletes`. It uses `find()` to get features of all three types from `source`. It also "cleans up" `updates` from the `boundedBy` property.

```js
const find = mode =>
  this.vectorSource
    .getFeatures()
    .filter(feature => feature.modification === mode);

const features = {
  updates: find("updated").map(feature => {
    feature.unset("boundedBy");
    return feature;
  }),
  inserts: find("added"),
  deletes: find("removed")
};
```

Comment: This looks interesting. Unfortunately I cannot test this since I am no longer using GeoServer.